# Global Land and Sea Surface Temperature Data

Tags: temperature, earth-system, satellites, weather-satellites

We are a spin-off from TU Munich and currently working on equipping a 
CubeSat with a thermal imager.

The imager should be able to acquire thermal/ir images with resolution of about 200m/px. In the future we see a high potential for building a constellation of such satellites to enable a 10min temporal resolution over all surface temperature data on the globe.

Do you use any data beside those publicly available from NASA and ESA? Which ones?
What may be some uses of such high temporal resolution surface temperature data?

Comment: not sure about NASA but I use - https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/map/clim/sst.shtml. Not sure about the value of 10 min temporal resolution over the sea. I mean SSTs do not really change that much over that scale. It is more a day or more...

Comment: I think many people should be interested in this, in particular for land and lake temperatures.  Contact the ESA Climate Change Initiative.  However,  your question is not in a suitable form for this site, as stated possible answers are "yes" and "no" depending on who answers, and we're looking for generic questions and answers.

Comment: @gerrit - the question can be reframed to make it objective. OP has to ask is there  a reason why we do not see 10 min temporal resolution for temperature over land or sea ?

Comment: @gansub It can indeed, and [we do, actually](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01431161.2012.716925).  And with a high resolution both spatially and in temperature, there could be interesting use cases.  Lake dynamics, nuclear plants illegally dumping waste water, rapid land surface temperature changes in response to wind or radiation changes… regrettably not below clouds though.

Comment: @Thomas Could you rephrase your question along the lines of "what may be some uses of such high temporal resolution surface temperature data"?

Comment: In the cryospheric studies satellite infrared  data is usually limmited by the fact that all comes for sun-synchronous orbits, therefore you can observe at only two times during the day, therefore it is of little help to study a system with a strong diurnal thermal cycle. 10min timeseries of surface temperature (at night time specially) would be very useful to study the surface energy balance.
I guess it would be also very interesting to study sea ice formation.

Comment: @ThomasGrübler How is the project going? When it will be/was launched?

Comment: @CamiloRada we raised governmental grants and also our first bigger seed investment :). Do not want to do too much advertisement here, but you can google OroraTech and follow our LinkedIn, FB etc pages.